# Android Chooser Intent for Camera Gallery AND Documents

Tags: android, android-intent, camera, gallery, documents

I'm having trouble creating a chooser intent that allows the users to select either a Camera App, a Gallery App, or a File Browser App.

So far, I can only get Camera + Gallery or Camera + File Browser but not all 3 options

In the below method it seems like following line is being ignored:

```
chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, galleryIntent);
```

Code:

```
public void openUploadIntent() {

    File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);

    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String fname = "ABCD_" + timeStamp;

    final File sdImageMainDirectory = new File(storageDir, fname);
    outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(sdImageMainDirectory);

    // Camera.
    final List<Intent> cameraIntents = new ArrayList<Intent>();
    final Intent captureIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    final PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
    final List<ResolveInfo> listCam = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(captureIntent, 0);
    for(ResolveInfo res : listCam) {
        final String packageName = res.activityInfo.packageName;
        final Intent intent = new Intent(captureIntent);
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));
        intent.setPackage(packageName);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
        cameraIntents.add(intent);
    }


    //Gallery.
    final Intent galleryIntent = new Intent();
    galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
    galleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    //Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);


    // Filesystem.
    final Intent fsIntent = new Intent();
    fsIntent.setType("*/*");
    fsIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);


    // Chooser of filesystem options.
    final Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(fsIntent, "Select Source");
    chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, galleryIntent);

    // Add the camera options.
    chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, cameraIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[cameraIntents.ize()]));

    startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, 99999);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Well i figured it out.
It looks like each call to EXTRA_INTIAL_INTENTS replaces the last.
This is my final working code (on Samsung Galaxy S)

```
public void openImageIntent() {

    File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);

    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String fname = "ABCD_" + timeStamp;

    final File sdImageMainDirectory = new File(storageDir, fname);
    outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(sdImageMainDirectory);

    // Camera.
    final List<Intent> cameraIntents = new ArrayList<Intent>();
    final Intent captureIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    final PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
    final List<ResolveInfo> listCam = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(captureIntent, 0);
    for(ResolveInfo res : listCam) {
        final String packageName = res.activityInfo.packageName;
        final Intent intent = new Intent(captureIntent);
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));
        intent.setPackage(packageName);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
        cameraIntents.add(intent);
    }


    //Gallery.
    Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

    // Filesystem.
    final Intent fsIntent = new Intent();
    fsIntent.setType("*/*");
    fsIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    cameraIntents.add(fsIntent);



    //Create the Chooser
    final Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(galleryIntent, "Select Source");
    chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, cameraIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[cameraIntents.size()]));

    startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, 99999);
}
```